# Understanding `Makevars` for linking to external C library in R package

Tags: rcpp, r-package

I am working on a package which includes C code from third-party library (SUNDIALS). The package compiles and works (i.e., is able to solve a test ODE) with the following `Makevars` file performing static linking

```
CXX=clang++

PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include
PKG_LDFLAGS = /usr/local/lib
PKG_LIBS= $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(PKG_LDFLAGS)/libsundials_cvode.a $(PKG_LDFLAGS)/libsundials_nvecserial.a
```

However, a slightly modified version (based on the example in R-Exts, i.e. -
 `PKG_LIBS = -L$(XML_DIR)/lib -lxml2`) of `Makevars` (below) fails

```
CXX=clang++

PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include
PKG_LDFLAGS = /usr/local/lib
PKG_LIBS= $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) -L$(PKG_LDFLAGS) -lsundials_cvode -lsundials_nvecserial -lm
```

fails with the following error message.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcppsbmod’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod/libs/Rcppsbmod.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod/libs/Rcppsbmod.so, 6): Library not loaded: libsundials_cvode.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod/libs/Rcppsbmod.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod’

Exited with status 1.
```

I am not sure why it is looking for the libraries in another location when I am specifying `PKG_LDFLAGS` as `/usr/local/lib`.

As an aside, the test example which comes which the SUNDIALS package compiles and works with the following command

```
gcc -Wall cvRoberts_dns.c -o cvRoberts_dns.exe -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/ -lsundials_cvode -lsundials_nvecserial -lm
```

So, I know that the library is installed properly and correct files (for linking) are available at `/usr/local/lib` location.

The entire package source code can be found at - https://github.com/sn248/Rcppsbmod

Any help or guidance will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

System-wide dynamic linking, as in your second use case which fails, requires the cooperation of the dynamic linker on your system.

That means after build and copyring the libraries to `/usr/local/lib` you must typically run `sudo ldconfig` to update the linker cache.

You can check if the libraries are know by grep'ing through the output of `ldconfig -p`.  On my system, no sundials:

```
edd@rob:~$ ldconfig -p | grep sundials
edd@rob:~$
```

Relatedly you can (locally) use different directories by declaring them in
`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/somefile.conf` -- but that is of course not portable and would not help you with a package designated for CRAN.

The use of *static* libraries you build as part of your package as in your first example would work as it does *not* require any system assistance.  It just takes longer the build the libraries each time.

Comment: Thank you @Dirk for your suggestion. On OSX (should have mentioned that before) there is no `ldconfig`, but there is `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache`. Running this command `sudo update_dyld_shared_cache | grep sundials` gives a long message such as `update_dyld_shared_cache: warning @rpath install name for system framework: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetCacheServicesExtensions.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/AssetCacheTetheratorService.xpc/Contents/Frameworks/MobileDeviceKitLite.framework/Versions/A/MobileDeviceKitLite`.

Comment: However, if static vs dynamic is not that important, I'll not make any changes, for now. My next challenge is to bundle the package such that there is no pre-requisite of having the library installed on the system (as installing sundials on Windows is not that trivial). Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

I am fighting with similar issues, c.f. [Runtime linking R-extension on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705490/runtime-linking-r-extension-on-macos). My current workaround is to set the `rpath` at compile time. In your case that would mean:

```
CXX=clang++

PKG_CPPFLAGS = -I../inst/include
PKG_LDFLAGS = /usr/local/lib
PKG_LIBS= $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) -L$(PKG_LDFLAGS) -lsundials_cvode -lsundials_nvecserial -lm -Wl,-rpath,$(PKG_LDFLAGS)
```

However, this does not fix your problems. Comparing the error messages I see one difference: In your case the library `libsundials_cvode.3.dylib` is not found, while in my case it is `@rpath/libaf.3.dylib`. This means that the library you installed identifies itself as `libsundials_cvode.3.dylib`. You can check this with

```
$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib 
/usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib:
    /usr/local/opt/sundials/lib/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.0.0)
```

In your case the second output line should not contain an absolute path but only the basename of the library. My installation uses `brew`, which typically uses absolute paths as library names. In some trivial tests I had no problem with linking an R extension with these libraries.

I see several possibilities:

- Try SUNDIAL from `brew`.
- Adjust the library path in your installed libraries with

  ```
  install_name_tool -id /usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib
  ```

  to use absolute paths.
- Adjust the library path in your installed libraries with

  ```
  install_name_tool -id '@rpath/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib' /usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib
  ```

  and set `rpath` as above.
- Adjust the name of the library your R extension is looking for with this addition to `Makevars`

  ```
  all: $(SHLIB)
      @if command -v install_name_tool; then install_name_tool -change libsundials_cvode.3.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvode.3.dylib $(SHLIB); fi
  ```

Comment: Ralf - Thanks for your answer. I tried your approach (slight change - with `-rpath` instead of `rpath`). I am getting following message (see below). Any suggestion is most welcome!

Comment: `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcppsbmod’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod/libs/Rcppsbmod.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod/libs/Rcppsbmod.so, 6): Library not loaded: libsundials_cvode.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/Rcppsbmod/libs/Rcppsbmod.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed`

Comment: I have checked `ls /usr/local/lib | grep sundials` gives `libsundials_cvode.1.0.0.dylib
libsundials_cvode.1.dylib
libsundials_cvode.3.1.0.dylib
libsundials_cvode.3.dylib
libsundials_cvode.a
libsundials_cvode.dylib
libsundials_cvodes.2.0.0.dylib
libsundials_cvodes.2.dylib
libsundials_cvodes.3.1.0.dylib
libsundials_cvodes.3.dylib
libsundials_cvodes.a
libsundials_cvodes.dylib`

Comment: @SN248 How did you install the SUNDIALS library?

Comment: Installing SUNDIALS on OS X and Linux I think is not so hard. I am specifically thinking about Windows. In any case, I do want users to be able to use this package even if they don't have SUNDIALS installed. I have seen this being done (nloptr, RCPPCAF), and will try to replicate whats being done there. Thanks.

Comment: Ralf Stubner - Thanks for your answer. I haven't tried your suggestion, but I was able to build the static library from source files and compile the package on my OS X machine. Now I am trying to do the same for Windows platform.Thanks again!